# Flexible hierarchies in Saiku Analytics

Tags: business-intelligence, olap-cube, mondrian, saiku

I have just started working on Mondrian and I am having a hard time understanding how to set hierarchies work.

Suppose that I have a Hospital dimension and I want to sum the amount of hospitals that are public or private in certain state. I have also my fact hospital with the appropriate measure hospital_amount.

The hierarchy I have built in the Schema Workbench is show below:

1- State 
2- Flag (Private or Public) 
3- City 
4- Hospital

Doing in this way I can analyse things in Saiku Analytics plugin without major concerns, provided that I maintain the presentation order of attributes (State, Flag, City,...). But, things turn a little complicated if I want change the order that fields will be presented in the report, in other words, what if I want to build another report in Saiku without using the flag attribute.

Even if I hide the flag, Saiku will continue using it to categorize the rest of the attributes from the hierarchy (City and Hospital).

Some people said that I need to create another hierarchy in the Schema Workbench only for the flag, but this won't let me use the flag in the drill menu of Hospital.

Is there any way to build reports in Saiku without being stuck into the hierarchy order, I mean choosing fields from hierarchy in a flexible way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you are using Saiku as a BI server plugin or on standalone.

If you are using standalone, which uses Mondrian 4, you can use the "has hierarchy" attribute in your schema instead of defining a strict hierarchy which effectively creates a hierarchy for each level, which can all act independently of one another.

Or in Mondrian 3 you could just do that manually.